# Setting custom icons for TYPO3 select options directly from database

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-8.x

I have created a form for DB inputs with TCA settings.

One of those is a select field that I would need a different icon for each option. Those Icon names (the core icons) are stored in db field icon(this can be changed):

```
+-----+----------------+------------------+
| uid | title          | icon             |
+-----+----------------+------------------+
| 1   | Active         | overlay-approved |
| 2   | Inactive       | overlay-readonly |
| 3   | Old            | overlay-info     |
| 5   | Limited access | overlay-locked   |
+-----+----------------+------------------+
```

The main data is loaded easily:

```
'issuer_id' => [
    'exclude' => true,
    'label'   => 'LLL:EXT:lu_nas/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:document.status',
    'config'  => [
        'type'                => 'select',
        'eval'                => 'required',
        'minitems'            => 0,
        'maxitems'            => 1,
        'foreign_table'       => 'tx_lunas_domain_model_status',
        'foreign_table_where' => 'ORDER BY tx_lunas_domain_model_status.title ASC',
        'items'               => [['', '',]],
    ],
],
```

where the TCA `tx_lunas_domain_model_status.php` settings `ctrl` is set to use title `'label' => 'title'` as name.

I know I can also add `'iconfile' => 'EXT:lu_nas/Resources/Public/Icons/Status.svg'` to use as default icon for all entries, but this I do not need (I need different for each entry).

So far I also found that I can add the custom items with icons as follows:

```
'items' => [
    ['', ''],
    ['Limited access', 5, 'overlay-locked'],
    ['Inactive', 3, 'overlay-info'],
    ['Old', 2, 'overlay-readonly'],
    ['Active', 1, 'overlay-approved'],
],
```

But how do I tell in what DB column the icon name is saved so that I can load this data directly from database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure, that you can't do that in TYPO3 at the moment, but you could use a userFunction. There you can just add the class for the icon.

```
'config' => [
    'type' => 'user',
    'userFunc' => YYY\XXX\TCA\TcaReferenceField::class . '->render',
]
```

The code would be something like this:

```
public function render(array $configuration, UserElement $userElement) {
    $row = $configuration['row'];

    // Do some Magic here.

    $select = '<label style="font-weight: 400;">' . self::MESSAGE_FIELD_LABEL;
    $select .= '<select name="' . $configuration['itemFormElName'] . '" class="form-control form-control-adapt" ' .
    'onchange=\'' . $configuration['fieldChangeFunc']['alert'] . '\'>';
    $select .= '<option value=""></option>';
    foreach ($contentElementUids as $siteName => $contentElementUid) {
        $isSelected = ($contentElementUid === (int) $configuration['itemFormElValue']);
        $select .= '<option ' . ($isSelected ? 'selected' : '') . ' value="' . $contentElementUid . '">' .
        $siteName . '</option>';
    }
    $select .= '</select></label>';

    return $select;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, will test this. But it still sounds strange, if there is an option `iconfile` and `title` where you can define the values, why is there no option like `iconfield` or just `icon` where I can define the db field with the value :/

Comment: Yeah, that's a nice missing feature. :)